# Docker file permission in Windows 10 pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker

I try to run my rails project on Docker Windows 10 pro.
I usually program this project on the mac, but my colleagues use windows, so I try to set it up with docker.

but I met a ??? permission problem so I can't run bundle install.
Any Ideas ?

```
C:\Users\tmaekawa\proj>docker-compose run web ls -la
ls: cannot access '.env.development': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Gemfile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Rakefile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'config.ru': No such file or directory
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8192 Mar 21 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 21 10:42 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Mar 21 08:13 .bundle
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? .env.development
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Mar 21 10:25 .git
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  536 Mar 21 00:18 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  438 Mar 21 00:18 .project
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   30 Mar 21 00:18 .rspec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    6 Mar 21 08:22 .ruby-version
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  492 Mar 21 10:22 Dockerfile
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Gemfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1614 Mar 21 00:18 Guardfile
```

When running bundle install, I got the following error becouse of Gemfile permission problem.

```
C:\Users\tmaekawa\proj>docker-compose run web bundle install --without production
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:431:in `initialize':  (Bundler::Dsl::DSLError)
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /myapp/Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:431:in `open'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:431:in `block in read_file'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118:in `filesystem_access'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:430:in `read_file'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/dsl.rb:46:in `eval_gemfile'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/plugin.rb:60:in `gemfile_install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:60:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/settings.rb:143:in `temporary'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Run again same command, I got another error.

```
C:\Users\tmaekawa\proj>docker-compose run web bundle install --without production
Could not locate Gemfile
```

**ADDTIONAL INFO**
RUN docker info from cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\tmaekawa\proj>docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 87
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 87
 Images: 229
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.76-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.943GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: O2AV:RXYB:YEHH:2HBL:JBSZ:DEO6:OK2N:7GFU:WQMX:BENM:JHTK:JFSS
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 35
  Goroutines: 52
  System Time: 2020-03-21T12:30:31.003329328Z
  EventsListeners: 3
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

run docker-compose --version

```
C:\Users\tmaekawa\proj>docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

Comment: Hi i'm not usig docker on Windows because it's just was not designed for Windows (i know Windows tries to keep up) but... 
Have you installed docker sucessfully? please run 'docker info'
How have you installed docker-compose? plese run 'docker-compose --version'

Comment: Just added docker info and docker-compose --version. Please check it.

Comment: Can you add your compose file?

Comment: And, how do you have docker in windows? Is it docker-for-windows? Have you tried it in ubuntu or alpine WSL2?

Comment: Obviosly you've installed Docker Desktop for Windows https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows (configrm please) since it uses virtualization i'm not sure if docker-compose will work at all beeng istalled as tool on your desktop directly not in same virtual machine..

Comment: After reading the docker introduction docs, this problem was self-solved. And somehow the above problem could not be reproduced.I am very worried why this happened, but now that the problem has been resolved, I will complete it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not using WSL2 only using Docker Desktop for Windows on Windows 10 pro.